# Is there a way to achieve better accuracy than double but with better performance than BigDecimal?

Tags: java, performance, double, bigdecimal, mandelbrot

I am creating a mandelbrot set application in java, but after a certain zoom it starts to look weird because `double`s are not accurate enough. I refactored my code to work with `BigDecimal`s, but the performance was absolutely terrible.

Is there a way to achieve at least a little more accuracy while still having acceptable performance?

Comment: There's actually a 128-bit floating point library that you can use, described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21071907/1361506).

Comment: there is a post about performance problem with bigDecimal https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39921191/is-there-a-way-to-make-bigdecimal-faster-than-i-have-here

Comment: Do you have enough iterations? The deeper the zoom, the more iterations are needed.

Comment: @WeatherVane yes, I definitely have enough iterations.

Comment: Given the nature of Mandlebrot, the most you can gain by changing the data type is to increase the amount of zooming you can do before it goes weird. The question is whether the increased zoom depth you will get with a given data type is worth the performance cost.